# Prove an equation concerns about $(\Delta f)\circ g$.

Tags: derivatives, laplacian

> Suppose $g:[0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2,\;(r,\varphi)\mapsto(r\cos\varphi,r\sin\varphi)$. $X$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash H$ where $H=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\;\big|\;x\leq0,\;y=0\}$. Prove 
>   \begin{equation*}
> (\Delta f)\circ g=\frac{\partial^2(f\circ g)}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f\circ g}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial^2 (f\circ g)}{\partial \varphi^2}
> \end{equation*}
>   on $g^{-1}(X)$, where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian operator.

It suffices to prove the equality holds at each given point $(r,\varphi)$, but I don't know how to expand explicitly $(\triangle f)\circ g(r,\varphi)$.

$\Delta f=\partial_1^2+\partial_2^2 f$.

Comment: What's your definition of the Laplacian?

Comment: $\triangle f=\partial_1^2+\partial_2^2 f$.

Comment: OK. Then all there is to this question is to apply the multivariable chain rule repeatedly. $x(r,\phi) = r \cos \phi,\ y(r,\phi) = r \sin \phi)$, and, for example, $\frac{\partial (f \circ g)}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial (f \circ g)}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial (f \circ g)}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial (f \circ g)}{\partial x} \cos(\phi) + \frac{\partial (f \circ g)}{\partial y} \sin(\phi)$. Compute $\partial_r,\ \partial^2_r,\ \partial_\phi, \partial^2_\phi$ and after a lot of algebra the result will follow

Comment: It's not completely obvious that finding those partials is what you have to do, but this approach works, and it's the approach that the problem is set up for. Alternatively, you can find the inverse to $g$ and compute $\partial_x,\ \partial_x^2,\ \partial_y,\ \partial_y^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\fa}{\forall}$
$\newcommand{\vp}{\varphi}$
$\newcommand{\ptl}{\partial}$
$\newcommand{\fptl}{\frac{\ptl}{\ptl}}$
$\newcommand{\lk}{\left[}$
$\newcommand{\rk}{\right]}$
$\newcommand{\Da}{\Delta}$

$\fa x=(r,\vp)\in g^{-1}(X)$, we have 
    \begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\ptl^2(f\circ g)}{\ptl r^2}(r,\vp) &=&\frac{\ptl}{\ptl r}\lk\fptl{(f\circ g)}{r}(r,\vp)\rk=\fptl{}{r}\lk\ptl_1f\circ g(x)\cos\vp+\ptl_2 f\circ g(x)\sin\vp\rk  \\
&=&\ptl_1^2f\circ g(x)\cos^2\vp+2\ptl_{12}^2f\circ g(x)\sin\vp\cos\vp+\ptl_2^2f\circ g(x)\sin^2\vp,\\
\frac{1}{r}\frac{\ptl(f\circ g)}{\ptl r}(r,\vp)  &=&\ptl_1f\circ g(x)\frac{\cos\vp}{r}+\ptl_2 f\circ g(x)\frac{\sin\vp}{r},  \\
\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\ptl^2(f\circ g)}{\ptl \vp^2}(r,\vp)  &=&\ptl_1^2f\circ g(x)\sin^2\vp+\ptl_2^2f\circ g(x)\cos^2\vp-\ptl_2 f\circ g(x)\frac{\sin\vp}{r}-\ptl_1f\circ g(x)\frac{\cos\vp}{r}\\
&&-2\ptl_{12}^2 f\circ g(x)\sin\vp\cos\vp.
\end{eqnarray*}
    So $\frac{\ptl^2(f\circ g)}{\ptl r^2}(r,\vp)+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\ptl(f\circ g)}{\ptl r}(r,\vp)+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\ptl^2(f\circ g)}{\ptl \vp^2}(r,\vp)=\ptl_1^2f\circ g(r,\vp)+\ptl_2^2f\circ g(r,\vp)=\Da f\circ g(r,\vp)$.